# Appending values to all keys of python dictionary

Tags: python

I have the following dictionary:

```
dic={'a': {'aa': [], 'ab': [], 'ac': []}, 'b': {'ba': [], 'bb': [], 'bc': []}}
```

I want to append three values to either all keys in 'a' or 'b'.
Following example works:

```
dic['a']['aa'].append(value_a)
dic['a']['ab'].append(value_b)
dic['a']['ac'].append(value_c)
```

Any way where I can do this in one single line.
What I'm searching for is something like the following:

```
dic['a'][*] = [value_a, value_b, value_c]
```

Where * is a wildcard indexing all keys in dic['a'].

As the complexity of the dictionary in my actual program grows my current working example becomes unreadable. So my motivation for this is mainly readability.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a "one-line" solution or does a "two-line" loop work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a *true* one-liner (i.e., not writing a `for`loop in one line) it is possible to use `map` and exploit the mutability of dicts:

```
dic={'a': {'aa': [], 'ab': [], 'ac': []}, 'b': {'ba': [], 'bb': [], 'bc': []}}
vals = [1,2,3]
key = 'a'

map(lambda kv: dic[key][kv[0]].append(kv[1]), zip(dic[key], vals))
```

This will return `[None, None, None]` but the dict will be updated. However, I would suggest that it would be better to use an explicit `for` loop, as a two-liner:

```
for k, v in zip(dic[key], vals):
    dic[key][k].append(v)
```

Note that this will add a separate value to each of the entries in the dict, as this is what I interpret to be what is wanted.

Comment: It is correct that my appended values are separate.

Comment: The for loop is definitely more readable than assigning each value per line. I still feel that there might be an even more descriptive way of doing this however.

Answer (score 3):

If a loop is acceptable for your single-line solution, then this may be used.

```
for key in dic['a']: dic['a'][key].append(value)
```

If you have a list of values, you can `extend` the list.

```
for key in dic['a']: dic['a'][key].extend([value_a, value_b, value_c])
```